# $|X|=|[0,1[|=|\mathbb{R}|$

Tags: analysis

I hope the title is not too confusing, let me clarify this first:

**Question: Show that every real number is equivalent to exactly one real number in the interval [0,1[**

What I know, or think to know is that I am trying to proof a bijection here, if I succeeded in doing this I can say that the two sets are of the same cardinality and all the points get mapped in a one to one correspondence.

**My attempt at solving this problem:**

Let $X = [0,1[=\lbrace \forall a \in \mathbb{R} \mid 0 \leq a < 1 \rbrace$

I came up with the following function:
\begin{align} f: \mathbb{R} &\longrightarrow X  \\ x & \longmapsto -e^{-x^2}+1\end{align}
At first sight this looked correct to me, but while this function is surjective, it is not injective. Is there any other way I can attempt at solving this problem? Or do I just need to find another, more suitable function to satisfy my conditions?

While I have struggled with this for a long while, plus read the similar questions on math SE, what still puzzles me the most is the left closed, right open interval they're introducing. It seems to me like functions that might satisfy such an interval will always include quadratic exponents.

Comment: What does it mean for two numbers to be 'equivalent' ?

Comment: Let $x$ be in $\mathbb{R}$ and $x' \in \mathbb{R}$ then $x=x'$, so I would only need to satisfy the injection statement?

Comment: By that definition, $2$ is not equivalent to any real number in the interval $[0,1)$.

Comment: I am fairly certain that this question has been covered so many times before on this site. Have you tried searching for it?

Comment: @AsafKaragila yes I did search on this site already, as mentioned in my post already. As I said, the bounds are the problem. It seems to me like this question belongs more into equivalence classes, but I wouldn't have any idea how to proceed from there as well, but it would of course nullify all the work I have done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is slightly easier to make a bijection ]0,1]->R:

if x is not of form 2^-n, n>=0 integer, then f(x)=ctg πx;
if x is of form 2^-n then f(x)=ctg πx/2

It is difficult to come up with 1-1 function, because R is open and [0,1[ is closed on one end and you need to tuck extra point.

Comment: I understand this, I will accept it as an answer. I believe that there are some wrong definitions in this questions that I first need to correspond with my professors before it has any real value to look deeper in it. Thanks for your contribution and sorry for the confusion :-)